# React-try to acces through fetch() method to particular data

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I have the following code where use a fetch() method to access a price of bitcoin.
But I want to access the "rate" prorperty of a particular currency, not all of them.

```
class Bitcoin extends Component {
constructor() {
    super()
        this.state = { 
            bpi: {}
        }
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/USD.json')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);

            const { bpi } = data;
            this.setState( { bpi } )

        })
}



_renderCoin() {
    console.log(this.state.bpi);
    const { bpi } = this.state;

    return Object.keys(bpi)
        .map(coin => {
            // console.log(coin)
            return(
                <div className={styles.info} key={coin}>
                    1 BTC are {bpi[coin].rate}
                    <span className={styles.money}>{coin}</span>
                </div>

            )

        })

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work...

Comment: Comes out following error:

app.js:33311 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at Bitcoin._renderCoin (app.js:33311)
    at Bitcoin.render (app.js:33337)
    at finishClassComponent (app.js:27117)
    at updateClassComponent (app.js:27080)
    at beginWork (app.js:27898)
    at performUnitOfWork (app.js:30636)
    at workLoop (app.js:30676)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (app.js:12965)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev......

Comment: I checked your code locally. it is working fine. you need to change _renderCoin to render function. can you confirm?

Comment: Abhishek can you please write what do you mean? Maybe I am understanding wrongly. Thank you